# How to prove that this integral operator converges to e^-x?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I have this integral operator:

$ L[y]=\int_0^x (s-y(s) ds) $

Applying the operator to $y_0(x)=0$, I've found

$y_1(x)=(1/2)x^2$,

$y_2(x)=(1/2)x^2-(1/6)x^3$

$y_3(x)=(1/2)x^2-(1/4)x^3+(1/24)x^4$

It seems that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}   y_n(x)=1/ e^x$

But, given [taylor series](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor%20series%20e%5E-x),  how can I prove this?

Thanks for your time

Comment: 1) In your $y_3$ you have a $(1/4)$. Should it be $(1/6)$? 2) It is not really $1/e^x$, but $1/e^x-1+x$, right? What tools is this connected with in your course(if any)? It might help in giving a better answer. Welcome to Math.SE.

Comment: No, it is $(1/4)$, but i think I've got a answer, because in the limit $(1/24)x^4$, will outgrow all other terms in $y_3$ and so on, in $y_2$ the term that rules will be  $−(1/6)x^4$.

Comment: It should be $(1/6)$. It comes from integrating $s^2/2$ from $0$ to $x$, which yields $x^3/6$.

Comment: God, you're right, I made a mistake, and a big one.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Finding the suspect**

So, you are looking at
$$
y_0(x)=0,\quad \text{and}\quad y_n(x)=\int_0^x (s-y_{n-1}(s))\,ds.\tag{*}
$$
First we note that *if* $y_n$ converges to some function $y$, then so does $y_{n-1}$, and we could suspect that $y$ satisfies
$$
y(x)=\int_0^x(s-y(s))\,ds.
$$
Differentiating, we find that
$$
y'(x)=x-y(x),\quad y(0)=0.
$$
This is a linear differential equation, which has solution
$$
y(x)=e^{-x}-1+x.
$$
Thus, this function is clearly our candidate.

**Step 2: Prove it is guilty:**

By doing a Taylor expansion of our suspect, we find that
$$
y(x)=\sum_{k=2}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}x^k.
$$
Now, what if we can show that the partial sums, up to a renumbering of one, coincide with the $y_n$? Let us try to show by induction that the $y_n$ defined in $(*)$ satisfies
$$
y_n(x)=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}x^k,\quad \forall n\geq 1.\tag{**}
$$
Now $y_1(x)=x^2/2$, so the first step is OK. Assume that it is true for $n-1$, i.e. that
$$
y_{n-1}(x)=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}x^k.
$$
Then, integrating, we find that (we integrate, and at one step put $l=k+1$)
$$
\begin{split}
y_n(x)&=\int_0^x(s-y_{n-1}(s))\,ds\\
&=\int_0^x \Bigl(s-\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}s^k\Bigr)\,ds\\
&=\frac{x^2}{2}-\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}\\
&=\frac{x^2}{2}+\sum_{l=3}^{n+1}\frac{(-1)^l}{l!}x^l\\
&=\sum_{l=2}^{n+1}\frac{(-1)^l}{l!}x^l
\end{split}
$$
Thus, $(**)$ is proven by induction. Now, recognizing the series expansion of $e^{-x}$, we find that, indeed,
$$
y_n(x)\to e^{-x}-1+x
$$
as $n\to+\infty$.

Comment: When you wrote "**Now, what if we can show that the partial sums, up to a renumbering of one, coincide with..**", did you mean that no matter if $n$ gets bigger, the summation will be the the same? proving that at the limit $y_n$ converges to $1/(e^x)$$-1+x$

Comment: The only thing I meant was that the sum was from $2$ to $n+1$ and not $n$. It was not clearly written, though...